# as.triangle producing long table instead of triangle shape

Tags: r

I am brand new to programming in R, but have experience in other languages.  I am attempting to create an actuarial triangle using the as.triangle in the `ChainLadder` package, but it is coming out as a long table instead of triangular.

My code is as follows:

```
 leo_step2 <- structure(list(DEVELOPMENTDATE = structure(c(18331, 18331, 18338, 18338, 18338, 18345, 18345, 18345, 18345, 18352, 18352, 18352, 18352), class = "Date"), 
               EFFYEAR = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), 
               EFFMNTH = c("03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03"), 
               DevWeek = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5), 
               sales = c(4, 6, 11, 5, 4, 19, 2, 1, 3, 9, 4, 2, 4), 
               premium = c(777, 7000, 1221, 1360, 300, 7000, 500, 100, 550, 7000, 3000, 1100, 1200)), 
          class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), 
          groups = structure(list( DEVELOPMENTDATE = structure(c(18331, 18338, 18345, 18352), class = "Date"), 
                                   EFFYEAR = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), EFFMNTH = c("03", "03", "03", "03"), 
                                   .rows = list(1:2, 3:5, 6:9, 10:13)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
                             class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE)) 


leo_march <- subset(leo_step2, EFFYEAR=='2020' & EFFMNTH=='03')

leo_tri_incr <- as.triangle(leo_march, origin="DEVELOPMENTDATE", dev="DevWeek", "sales", na.rm=FALSE)

leo_tri_cum <- incr2cum(leo_tri_incr)

leo_tri_cum

#                DevWeek
# DEVELOPMENTDATE  1  2  3  4  5
#      2020-03-10  4 NA NA NA NA
#      2020-03-17 11 16 20 NA NA
#      2020-03-24 19 21 22 25 NA
#      2020-03-31  9 13 NA NA NA
```

The numbers it is showing are correct, but it just isn't formatting as a triangle.  Can anyone help?

Comment: This is likely to depend on the exact structure of `leo_step2` - you can share this data easily using `dput(leo_step2)` and pasting the output into your question (if short enough).

Comment: Sure but it is too long for one comment, so I will paste over 2 comments.  I also had to create some fake data rather than real data, but the structure is the same.

Comment: structure(list(DEVELOPMENTDATE = structure(c(18331, 18331, 18338, 
18338, 18338, 18345, 18345, 18345, 18345, 18352, 18352, 18352, 
18352), class = "Date"), EFFYEAR = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), EFFMNTH = c("03", 
"03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"03"), DevWeek = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5), sales = c(4, 
6, 11, 5, 4, 19, 2, 1, 3, 9, 4, 2, 4), premium = c(777, 7000, 
1221, 1360, 300, 7000, 500, 100, 550, 7000, 3000, 1100, 1200)),

Comment: class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), groups = structure(list(
    DEVELOPMENTDATE = structure(c(18331, 18338, 18345, 18352), class = "Date"), 
    EFFYEAR = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), EFFMNTH = c("03", "03", 
    "03", "03"), .rows = list(1:2, 3:5, 6:9, 10:13)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))